# Issue when running a groovy script for "function_score"?

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

```
def score = 0;
// terms: list of tokens
for(term in terms) {
    q_term_freq = terms​.countBy { it }​[term]; // for frequency of each term in terms
    term_freq = _index[field][term].tf(); 
    doc_freq = _index[field][term].df(); 
    score += term_freq * doc_freq * q_term_freq;
};
score;
```

When I run this I get an error `GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[No such property: terms\u200b for class: Script86.

What is going wrong? AFAIK `countBy` is valid function.

Comment: `\u200b` is unicode for Zero Width Space. rewrite the script or make sure there is no unicode character with `terms`.

Comment: @dmahapatro I rewrote the script and the problem was solved! thanks

Comment: @dmahapatro Could you please add an answer to this question so that I can accept it!

Comment: Done. Although it would be preferable to delete the question if it adds no value to a fellow reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\u200b` is unicode for Zero Width Space.

Rewrite the script or make sure there is no unicode character present with `terms`.